# ¿Por que si poseo un formato de codificación al ejecutara archivo en java aparece así (Ã± y Ã©)?

Tags: java, cmd, codificación

1. Elemento de lista

Hola, queridos amig@s, Dios les bendiga, un gusto saludarles.
Tengo un error con lenguaje JAVA, cuando ejecuto el archivo en windows 10 desde el cmd o incluso también probé con VSC los caracteres los imprime con otros signos. LA CODIFICACIÓN DE TODO LO TENGO EN UTF-8. En VSC, aparece UTF-8 también.

RESUMEN EN LA FOTO

[image: RESUMEN EN LA FOTO]

Comment: Suele ser un problema de la codificación de los caracteres ya que los acentos no los detecta. Deberían de estar en UTF-8. Te daría una respuesta si supiera como tienes configurado tu PC o que tienes que seguir para solventarlo

Comment: La codificación del archivo la ves en la barra inferior, después de los números de línea y columna, si no dice "UTF-8" haz click en el nombre del formato que te aparezca y cámbialo.

Comment: La codificación está en UTF-8. No entiendo porqur aún persiste el error. Es un poco incómodo porque ya probé con otros lenguajes y ni hay ningún problema. Solamente me pasa en JAVA.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java estás utilizando? Edit: se comprueba con "java -version"

Comment: ESTA VERSIÓN TENGO: java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)